# What percentage of a 20 volume solution is actually hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, gas-laws

Not too sure how to go about answering this question. I know that volume Strength is the volumes of O2 released on the decomposition of one volume of H2O2 at STP. However, I'm not certain where to go from here, nor if I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: If your hydrogen peroxide solution is 20 vol% hydrogen peroxide, then for every 1L of solution, 200 mL of that is hydrogen peroxide. Now use their respective densities to convert everything to masses, then moles.

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule confusingly, "20 volume" doesn't necessarily refer to 20% v/v: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide#Availability

Answer (score 1):

When a 3% solution of H2O2 decomposes completely, it produces 10 times as much volume of gas as the initial volume of liquid. This is the common hydrogen peroxide available in stores. I buy it often.

So, it would seem intuitive that "20 volume Hydrogen Peroxide" would be a 6% solution.

To check, let's take 1 liter of H2O2 and let it decompose: 20 liters of O2 is 20/22.4 = 0.893 moles of O2. To get 0.893 moles of O2, you must have started with 2 x 0.893 = 1.786 moles of H2O2, which weighs 60.7 grams. It looks like it's close to 6% (ignoring the density of the 6% solution).